zkSync Operators
I am trying to understand, from the zkSync documentation, which operators participate in the transaction lifecycle on zkSync.
I have seen the following defined on the docs:

The sequencer: bundles and orders transactions sent from users
The Prover (boojum): creates the zk proofs

However, I do not understand:

How the proofs are sent to the L1?
How the transaction bundle is sent to the L1?
Are there any other operators involved in the Tx lifecycle?

I have seen while digging around in the source code, a validator system referred to.
Is this the entity that submits the proofs and the TX bundles?
If so, is this a centralized or decentralized network? What are their responsibilities?
Edit: I am also seeing "batcher" referred to in this Tx

What we call Operator nowadays is actually a set of components indeed. Summarizing it is mainly what you mentioned

Sequencer - receives txs, executes, bundles them into batches, and send them to L1.
Prover - Checks a new batch is available, generates a proof for it, sends the proof to L1, and finalizes the batch

In the current design of the system, where it is still centralized, there is a service (Let’s call it ETH Sender) that is performing the L1 transactions. So, whenever a batch is ready to be commited, or a proof is ready to be verified, this is the service actually sending the tx (so, sort of the personification of the operator).
As soon as we decentralized the sequencer (first part ot be decentralized), it means that many Validators will be the ones commiting batches, but, for some time, a single “Prover operator”. will be working on generating proofs and sending the to L1.


How the proofs are sent to the L1?


The “Prover operator” generates the proof. Then ETH Sender checks a new proof is available, and sends to zkSync L1 contract calling the proveBatches function.


How the transaction bundle is sent to the L1?


The Sequencer compresses the pubdata for the entire L1 batch of transactions. Then the ETH Sender checks a new batch is available to be commited, and sends it to zkSync L1 contracts using the commitBatches function.


Are there any other operators involved in the Tx lifecycle?


So, as I mentioned above, there are a few “components”, but for now, a single “entity” responsible for the whole tx flow. As we decentralize we will have Validators (diong the role of Sequencer + part of ETH Sender), and Provers (doing the role of Prover operator + part of ETH Sender as well).
Here is also a good source from the community that dives into the transaction flow and different pieces. https://blog.quarkslab.com/zksync-transaction-workflow.html
